Differential of the evaluation map of the Kontsevich moduli space
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and $\beta$ a curve class on it. We have the Kontsevich moduli space $\overline{\mathcal M}_g(X, \beta)$ of stable maps from genus $g$ curves to $X$ with class $\beta$.
We have the evaluation map from the moduli space of $1$-pointed stable maps
$$
ev : \overline{\mathcal M}_{g, 1}(X, \beta) \to X
$$
Let $(f : C \to X, p)$ be a point in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g, 1}(X, \beta)$, assume $C$ is smooth and $f$ is an embedding.
Then the tangent space of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,1}(X, \beta)$ is isomorphic to $H^0(N_f) \oplus T_p C$.
My question is, how to describe the differential of the evaluation map?
$$
dev_{(f,p)} : H^0(N_f) \oplus T_p C \to (f^* T_X) \otimes k(p)
$$
I know from Kollar's book on rational curves, the differential evaluation map from the morphism scheme $ev : Hom(C, X) \times C \to X$ has description
$$
\phi(p, f) + df_p = dev_{(f,p)} : H^0(f^* T_X) \oplus T_p C \to (f^* T_X) \otimes k(p)
$$
where $\phi(p,f) : H^0(f^* T_X) \to (f^* T_X) \otimes k(p)$ is the restriction map.
Is there a similar description for the stable map case?

How do you get that description of the tangent space? I would think there's an exact sequence relating those three things but it doesn't split.

I think the deformation-obstruction of $(f,p)$ is controlled by $\mathrm{Ext}^i({f^* \Omega_X^1 \to \Omega_C(p)}, \mathcal{O}_C)$ for $i = 1, 2$. When $f$ is an embedding, the tangent sheaves are both locally free and $T_C(-p) \to f^* T_X$ is injective, the cokernel is $N_f \oplus T_C|_p$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^{1} = H^0(N_f) \oplus T_C|_p$.

I mean the cokernel is isomorphic to $N_f \oplus T_C \mid_p$ but the isomorphism is not canonical. To describe the map you only want to use a canonical isomorphism, so it's better to just express it as H^0 of the cokernel.  But then it's obvious what the answer should be: It must be the restriction map $H^0(\operatorname{cokernel} )\to \operatorname{cokernel}  \otimes k(p) = (f^* T_X) \otimes k(p)$.

One just has to prove this, and then I think one can do this by explicitly representing tangent vectors by curves over $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ and describing the tangent space in those terms.

Could you explain why $\mathrm{cokernel} \otimes k(p) = (f^* T_X) \otimes k(p)$?

Just because the map is $0$ mod $p$ since it's obtained by restricting the map $T_C \to f^* T_X$ to $T_C(-p)$, whose sections are the sections of $T_C$ that vanish at $p$.

I see! Thanks for answering!
